Integrated Fingerprint Sensor not recognized by Ubuntu
I'm having trouble getting the fingerprint sensor on my laptop working on Ubuntu. The fingerprint sensor is integrated into the touchpad. Here are the details:
System Information:

Laptop model: VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X571GT_F571GT
Ubuntu version: 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat)

Device Information:




Steps Taken:

Installed fprintd and libpam-fprintd.
Tried enrolling fingerprint using fprintd-enroll.
Checked system logs with journalctl -xe | grep fprintd.

Any help or guidance on getting the fingerprint sensor to work would be greatly appreciated.

different hardware but might this Ubunbtu Handbook reference help

Please don't post screenshots of the terminal. Copy the output of the terminal and paste it directly in your question and format the pasted output as code using the {_} icon above the edit window. See Why do people post screenshots of their terminals?
